# key error, time data does not match format

Tags: python, time, helper

I get the following error:

```
time data "2020-03-06" doesn't match the format %Y/%m/%d
```

but I don't see how I am wrong for using the current parameter
I am using the following code

```
tmp = dt.datetime.strptime(date[i], '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: From the error it's very clear ur using a wrong date format, check the column values.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggest the format is expecting "%Y/%m/%d", you have "2020-03-06"
replace the dash with backslashes.
i.e.

```
tmp = dt.datetime.strptime("2020/03/06", '%Y/%m/%d')
```

That should resolve the error.
Since it looks like date is stored as a string within date[i], you can do `date[i].replace("-","/")`

[image]